# How to access validator service in custom repository in Symfony

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using `@Assert\Choice` validation for a property in an entity.

`ApplicationQuestion.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * ApplicationQuestion
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="j_application_questions")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="JobsBundle\Repository\ApplicationQuestionRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class ApplicationQuestion
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Assert\Choice(choices={"free_text","boolean", "multiple_choice", "video"}, message="Choose a valid answer type")
     * @Expose()
     */
    protected $answer_type;

}
```

Creating a new `ApplicationQuestion`from `ApplicationQuestionRepository`

`ApplicationQuestionRepository.php`

```
<?php
class ApplicationQuestionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $data
     * @param Job $job
     * @return bool|ApplicationQuestion
     */
    private function createNewQuestion($data, Job $job)
    {
        if( $data['answer_type'] == 'multiple_choice' && !array_key_exists('answer_choices', $data) ){
            return false;
        }

        $question = new ApplicationQuestion();
        $question
            ->setJob($job)
            ->setQuestion($data['question'])
            ->setAnswerType($data['answer_type'])
            ->setQuestionFor('job_application')
            ;
        if( $data['answer_type'] == 'multiple_choice' )
            $question->setAnswerChoices($data['answer_choices']);

        return $question;
    }

}
```

How go I access the `validator` service to validate for `assert` condition before inserting. So want to do something like this in `ApplicationQuestionRepository`

```
$this->get('validator')->validate($question);
```

but not sure how to inject the `validator` service inside the custom repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a service that uses the entity manager and your validator service as a dependency. Call it ApplicationQuestionService or something like that.

You then have all the dependencies you need for validating and saving your question.

Alternatively you could look at a factory: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Comment: Thanks. I think service would be a better option. Cheers!

Comment: but you can also use it in the repository . that sound more simple .